# Sequence in $\Bbb Q$ that converges to $0$ under $d_E$ and to $1$ under $d_2$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

I am looking for a sequence in $\Bbb Q$ that converges to $0$ under the Euclidian metric and to $1$ under the 2-adic metric $d_2$. This metric is defined by the 2-adic absolute value as $d_2(x, y) = |x-y|_2 = 2^{-\text{ord}_2(x-y)}$  for $x ≠ y$. As $|3^{-n}|_2 = 2^{-0} = 1$ for all $n ∈ \Bbb N$, this sequence seems to "be the constant sequence $(1)_{n ∈ \Bbb N}$ w.r.t. the 2-adic metric", so my guess would be that the sequence $(3^{-n})_{n ∈ \Bbb N}$ will suffice. However, I run into a problem when I try to run the proof neatly. Indeed, what I want to show is the following:

$$(\forall \varepsilon ∈ \Bbb R_{>0})(\exists N ∈ \Bbb N)(\forall n ∈ \Bbb N)\left(n ≥ N \Rightarrow d_2(1, 3^{-n}) = 2^{-\text{ord}_2(3^{-n} - 1)} < \varepsilon\right),
$$

but this suddenly isn't so clear.. The value of $\text{ord}_2(3^{-n} - 1)$ really seems to depend on $n$ in an non-trivial way. Am I even right that this sequence will suffice? If so, how do I prove it correctly?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3264177/96384

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take$$x_n=1-\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}.$$It clearly converges to $0$ with respect to the Euclidean distance. Besides, $d_2(x_n,1)=2^{-n}$ and so…

Comment: Aha, thanks! So was I indeed wrong about my guess? Or is it true but is the proof unnecessarily tedious?

Comment: I was going to say $x_n=\dfrac1{1+2^n}$; would that work too?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman Your example will not work; it is not true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{ord}_2(3^{-n}-1)=0$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, that will work too.